# php exec tesseract outputs empty array

Tags: php, exec, tesseract

I installed tesseract v3.01 on windows 7. I added tesseract path to the environments variables. I obtains the right output after typing this command in the cmd windows: "tesseract test.tif test".

When I try to get the same result in php using the folowing script, I get an empty array and no file is generated:

```
<?php

try {
    exec("tesseract.exe test.tif test", $msg);
    var_export($msg);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}

?>
```

Any clue ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

try {
    $msg = array(); // TRY THIS 
    exec("tesseract.exe test.tif test", $msg);
    var_export($msg);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}

?>
```

Comment: I still have the same empty array as a result :(

Comment: So I tested again... after copying the tesseract files into the php script' folder It was working well. I tried to use putenv(). Tesseract is declared in the path environment variable...

Comment: Ok, it is because of permissions, perhaps. Try this  exec("tesseract.exe test.tif test 2>&1", $msg);

Answer (score 0):

Why not try specifying the full path to tesseract?

Not sure how to do this on windows, but on mac terminal, I type in `which tesseract` and it will find the full path of tesseract. You can then enter that full path, in my case `/usr/local/bin/tesseract` into the exec command.

```
try {
    $msg = array();
    exec("/usr/local/bin/tesseract test.tif test", $msg);
    var_export($msg);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```