# Trying to output java file in php file

Tags: java, php

Well, I did following steps to call java class or methods or even simple output to my localhost

1. I install java SE which is successfully working
2. I check through CMD that my javac is working or not and it's working
3. I also use to run Java/php bridge.war file using following command
   `java -classpath JavaBridge.war TestInstallation` works fine

But now when I am trying to execute following code:

```
<?php 
        require_once("java/Java.inc");
        //echo java("java.lang.System")->getProperties();
        require_once("first.java");
        //require_once("apples.class");
        //exec("java -version",$output);
        //print_r($output);//return empty....:(
        //$obj = new Java("apples.class");  
    ?>
```

Expected output is:

```
Hello only
```

Coming output is following whole code of first.java file

```
class apples{ public static void main(String args[]) { System.out.println("Hello only"); } }
```

I don't know what to do? It's just simple java code but later on using more complex code....
first.java file code:

```
 class apples{
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            System.out.println("Hello only");
        }
   }
```

Please help me in simple manner thanks.....in advanced:)

Comment: Have you opened the file "java/Java.inc" to see what it contains?

Comment: Yes, I did but it's contain following which I am not sure should I edit or not.....# define ("JAVA_HOSTS", 9267); define ("JAVA_SERVLET", false);
# define ("JAVA_HOSTS", "127.0.0.1:8787");
# define ("JAVA_HOSTS", "ssl://my-secure-host.com:8443");
# define ("JAVA_SERVLET", "/MyWebApp/servlet.phpjavabridge");
# define ("JAVA_PREFER_VALUES", 1);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128619/run-java-class-file-from-php-script-on-a-website

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860236/execute-java-class-in-php